# Парсинг цены coinmarketcap

Tags: php

Хочу спарсить цену на ETH и BTC с кмк, но почему-то цена выводится 1 раз, только на биток или эфир, как оптимизировать скрипт?

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/');
$objResponse = json_decode($json, true);
$btcprice=$objResponse['data']['quotes']['USD']['price'];
echo "$btcprice";

$json1 = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1027/');
$objResponse1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$ethprice=$objResponse1['data']['quotes']['USD']['price'];
echo "$ethprice";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно что именно требуется, что значит цена выводится 1 раз?
Я малость переделал скрипт, чтобы можно было разделить цены:

```
echo $btcprice.'</br>'.PHP_EOL;
echo $ethprice.'</br>'.PHP_EOL;
```

И получил в результате:

```
5318.52216098</br>
173.940774357</br>
```